# Repetição de valores dentro de um Dataframe

Tags: python, data.frame

Estou realizando uma análise de dados em um [*dataset*](https://www.kaggle.com/volpatto/temperature-timeseries-for-some-brazilian-cities) que exibe os dados de temperaturas (de janeiro a dezembro) ao longo dos anos.

Ao importar o *dataset* verifiquei que possui alguns valores imprecisos de temperaturas na faixa de 999.90. O que eu poderia fazer substituir esse valor pela média dos meses?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode primeiro substituir o valor `999.90` por `np.nan` e depois utilizar [`pandas.Dataframe.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                            

In [2]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                           

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame([[10,2,4,5], [20,7,8,9], [30, 999.9, 40, 50]], columns=list('ABCD'))  

In [4]: df                                                                                                                                            
Out[4]: 
    A      B   C   D
0  10    2.0   4   5
1  20    7.0   8   9
2  30  999.9  40  50

In [5]: df = df.replace(999.90, np.nan)    

In [6]: df                                                                                                                                            
Out[6]: 
    A    B   C   D
0  10  2.0   4   5
1  20  7.0   8   9
2  30  NaN  40  50


In [7]: df.fillna(df.mean())                                                                                                                          
Out[7]: 
    A    B   C   D
0  10  2.0   4   5
1  20  7.0   8   9
2  30  4.5  40  50

In [8]: df                                                                                                                                            
Out[8]: 
    A    B   C   D
0  10  2.0   4   5
1  20  7.0   8   9
2  30  NaN  40  50
```

Comment: Consegui. O notebook que estava usando bugou! Substituir os valores de  `999.90` por  `NaN` e posteriormente inserir no lugar dos `NaN` a média dos valores pelo seguinte comando `df_rec2_nan.fillna(df_rec2_nan.mean(0),inplace=True)` que resultou nos mesmos valores que a solução do drec4s. Obrigado!